# POST var in bindParam

Tags: php, post, pdo, var

Is it safe or not to use a POST var as below:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':'.$_POST[$field],$val);
```

or I need to check POST vars before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use $_POST variables as the *value*, not the parameter name.

The $_POST variable could contain spaces or other characters that are not valid parts of a parameter name. I'm concerned that if you are doing what you show, that you have formed an SQL query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn = :" . $_POST[$field];
```

Which is *definitely* not safe.

And there's no reason for the parameter names to be set to user input like that. Parameter names should be fixed by you, the programmer:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn = :myparam";
```

Then you bind using the same name. By the way, as long as you're using a reasonably recent version of PHP, you don't need the colon prefix in the bind call. You only need it in the SQL.

```
$stmt->bindParam("myparam", $_POST[$field]);
```

Comment: Thanks Bill for answer!